# Torrent slow download speed

Tags: proxy, bittorrent, internet-speed

I am having problems download torrents after my ISP implemented something to slowdown the torrent downloads. I am searched some solutions regarding. One possible solution was to use of proxy IP address, yet I didn't show any difference.

What possible solution is available out there for me that is (at mostly possible) free? I am experiencing an average DL speed of 20-30 Kbps from 1+Mbps (before ISP did something).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using uTorrent, the best way to achieve full speed is to force outgoing encryption. Open up your settings menu (`uTorrent > Preferences` on a Mac, or I believe `File > Settings` on a PC). Select the BitTorrent tab.  In the `Outgoing encryption` change it to forced. This way everything BitTorrent sends is encrypted, so the ISP can't identify it as torrent traffic.

Comment: I am using BitTorrent and it's weird that my speed is limited already from waht you said that `BitTorrent sends is encrypted.`

Comment: @Dr.Java It is only encrypted if you *force outgoing encryption*, otherwise it remains unencrypted.

Comment: I'm not following what you said.

Comment: By default, BitTorrent does **not** encrypt anything. When it is not encrypted, your ISP can identify the traffic and throttle it. However, if you set the Protocol encryption to `Force` then BitTorrent will only make encrypted connections. Because they are encrypted, your ISP cannot identify them and thus cannot throttle them.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know how to secure my torrent line with my ISP. Actually it did a significant increase on the speed (it doubled the speed from 20-30 to 40-60[average: 15kbps]). Is there other options to increase the DL speed aside from encryption?

Comment: @Dr.Java The encryption will beat the throttle from the ISP. There are other methods for increasing BitTorrent speeds in general. These include downloading torrents with lots of seeders, increasing your connections per torrent, and limiting other network traffic.

Comment: @Dr.Java - Encryption will not necessarily beat the throttle from the ISP - Even using the very primitive way we tackled the problem 15 years ago - by assigning unknown traffic to a low speed pool - will largely thwart using encryption as a workaround.

Comment: @Dr.Java If you liked my answer, please consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any single answer to this question - it really depends on what your ISP is doing.  The simplest solution, of-course, is to change to an ISP that does not try and discourage this kind of behaviour if thats an option.

Some thoughts as to how the ISP might be limiting you and what you can do about it.  Again, this is nothing more then (informed) speculation -

1. The ISP might be prioritising "known traffic" based on port and protocol, and then 
   putting everything else in a low bandwidth pool, assuming its peer to peer.  A VPN
   might punch through this limitation, particularly if the ISP has business customers
   who value high performance on VPN's.
2. The ISP could be looking at the number of simultaneous connections and deducing 
   from the quantity of connections (particularly inbound connections) that traffic 
   is most likely P2P and penalising this.
3. The ISP could be looking at traffic for "torrenting" signatures - encryption would
   frustrate this technique.
4. The ISP could do more complex heuristic matching to work out if you are torrenting -
   see [this paper](http://www.iis.se/docs/hjelmvik_breaking.pdf).

That said, the ISP probably has a LOT more vested in stopping you then you have in getting arround it if your budget is $0.  They are dealing with costs of infrastructure and possibly pressure from studios etc, and have a financial interest limiting them, along with that comes skills and hardware that put put on the wrong side of the game and if they are good at it, if you are not going to throw money at the problem you will probably loose.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detail explanation about how my ISP is monitoring torrent traffic. Anyways, among the four (4) speculations you've mentioned. What can be the optimum solution for me to take (in your opinion)?